# Uncomfortable rise and backsweep on wide mountain bike handlebars

Tags: handlebars

I've got a set of wide carbon bars on my mountain bike. I get painful wrists after riding because of the shape of the bars. They are pretty much flat with a slight backsweep. How do I know which bars I should buy and what is the benefit of rise and backsweep on handlebars?

Comment: You may have a fit expert take a look at your cockpit setup.  There several other factors that may be cheaper/easier to change before your handlebars.  You may look at your stem angle/length, and also where your shifters/brakes are positioned.  If you have your brakes/shifters rotated improperly, you can create an uncomfortable angle for your wrists that is painful, but easily fixed.

Comment: Sounds like your bike-fit needs a review.  Could be low handlebars and you've got too much weight on your hands so a slightly lower seat/higher bars/more upright position would help.  Voting to leave open because it might be bike fit, but if it goes off into medical then its definitely off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That "rise and backsweep" makes it easier to handle the bike when standing up. You'll notice that this is more pronounced on downhill bikes.

I am also uncomfortable on a flat bar, and I use bar-end bullhorns (I don't know if you could install these on a carbon bar).